# How to recover write priviledges for USB devices?

Tags: windows-vista, usb

I work on a corporate laptop (Windows Vista), and have been granted admin rights on that machine. An IT policy has been rolled out recently which lets me copy files from my USB devices but I cannot delete or write files in there.

When I try deleting a file, the pop up message says: "XXXXX could not be deleted. You do not have permission to delete this item."

I can't get any assistance on that from the IT desk, but given I have admin rights I should be able to change it myself.

I have looked into [this article about write protection of USB devices](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/18/how-to-enable-write-protection-of-usb-devices-under-windows/), however that key does not exist in my registry. Where else could the lock be?

Comment: What is the filesystem on the USB drive? If it is NTFS you may not have the right permission to delete it, even as admin. (But you can take ownership of the file and then give yourself permissions). If it is FAT or vFAT then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The device I'm interested in right now is an Asus Nexus 7, within the frame of android development. Not sure if that adds yet another layer of permissioning on top of basic file write permissions ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Nexus, but you can do a simple test: Plug it into a non-work PC (with none of your corporate IT policies ). If you get the same write/delete problem then the problem lies not [only] in policies.

Comment: Tried that already, it works on any other computer.